# Dojo InlineEditBox clears on click if initial value set programmatically

Tags: javascript, dojo

A Dojo [InlineEditBox](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.7/dijit/InlineEditBox) allows users to click on a piece of text, turning it into an edit box and allowing the text to be edited (and then the changes can be saved or cancelled).

In my case, I need to override the initial value of the text box programmatically (from a REST call, actually). A dojo bug (I assume) causes the InlineEditBox to be reset to the initial value when you click it, and you're left "editing" a text box with different text from the text that was in there before you clicked - not the best UX. Dojo seems to save the value when the InlineEditBox is first created *before* the value is set programmatically, and then applies that initial value when the box switches to edit mode.

So if I have a `div`, say with text "initial" and `id="testDiv"`, and this in my JavaScript:

```
require(["dijit/InlineEditBox", "dijit/form/Textarea", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(InlineEditBox, Textarea) {
  var editBox = new InlineEditBox({
    editor: Textarea,
    autoSave: false
  }, "testDiv").startup();
  var editText = "Click to edit text...";
  dojo.byId("testDiv").innerHTML = editText; // <-- what can I do instead?
});
```

Then in its normal state, the box contains "Click to edit text...", but when I click to edit that text, I'm left editing the text "initial" instead.

Here's a [fiddle demonstrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/562guLke/3/).

So my question is: how do I set the "saved value" of a Dojo InlineEditBox to override the initial value it saves on creation? (In my case I leave the div empty and the box is cleared when in edit mode.) I've played around in the console and can see a bunch of things I can do with the box object, and I've looked through the documentation, but can't find a way to set the value other than assigning something to its `innerHTML`.

The call to retrieve the value I want to set is asynchronous, so I can't set it at the time the box is created, it would have to be just afterwards. Happy to consider moving from Dojo 1.7 to a newer version if there's no other way, but it would mean a fair bit of regression testing, so if possible I'd want this to work with 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug - just improper use of widget. In fact, text node (before doubleclick) and textarea in edit mode are two different DOM elements. If you assign one's `innerHTML` property, second one remains unchanged. 
Instead of assigning text to `innerHTML`, set widget's value:

```js
require([
  "dijit/InlineEditBox", "dijit/form/Textarea", "dojo/domReady!"
], function(InlineEditBox, Textarea) {
  var editBox = new InlineEditBox({
    editor: Textarea,
    autoSave: false
  }, "testDiv");
  editBox.startup();
  var editText = "Click to edit text...";
  editBox.set("value", editText);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
<div id="testDiv">initial</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks, that did the trick. I'd tried doing `set("value", ...)` before, but on the wrong DOM element - I wasn't aware that there was a separate one for view and edit modes, but I guess that makes sense.